# Reading the environment variables of another process

Tags: c, windows, winapi, process, environment-variables

I'm trying to get a process environment strings, the code below is what I already wrote.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define ProcessBasicInformation 0

typedef struct _PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION {
    NTSTATUS  ExitStatus;
    PVOID     PebBaseAddress;
    ULONG_PTR AffinityMask;
    LONG      BasePriority;
    HANDLE    UniqueProcessId;
    HANDLE    InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
} PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION, *PPROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[]) {
  TCHAR   *app;
  DWORD    pid;
  HANDLE  proc;
  NTSTATUS nts;
  PVOID   rupp; // RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS, offset 0x10
  PVOID    env; // Environment, offset 0x48
  TCHAR   *buf;
  PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;
  MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION  mbi;

  if (argc != 2) {
    app = _tcsrchr(argv[0], '\\');
    _tprintf(TEXT("Usage: %s [PID]\n"), app ? ++app : argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }

  _stscanf_s(argv[1], TEXT("%lu"), &pid);
  if (!(proc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid))) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (!(nts = NtQueryInformationProcess(
    proc, ProcessBasicInformation, &pbi, sizeof(pbi), NULL
      ))) {
  if (ReadProcessMemory(
    proc, (PCHAR)pbi.PebBaseAddress + 0x10, &rupp, sizeof(rupp), NULL
      )) {
  if (ReadProcessMemory(proc, (PCHAR)rupp + 0x48, &env, sizeof(env), NULL)) {
     //what I need to do to get enironment strings?
  }
}
  }

  CloseHandle(proc);

  return 0;
}
```

Can somebody explain what I need to do to get environment strings of a process?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth `GetEnvironmentVariable` is to get the calling process' environment, OP want to get another remote process' environment.

Comment: I am not aware of a supported way of doing this. The lock that protects environment variables is process-local. You can't take the lock from another process. Environment variables are considered private to the process and should not be manipulated externally. If you want to manipulate a process's environment variables, you need to coordinate with the process. (See, for example, [the WM_SETTINGSCHANGE "Environment" notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497(v=vs.85).aspx).)

Comment: This isn't really something that you typically need to do, not to mention the fact that the location of environment variables could possibly change after program startup as a result of the Windows API function [`SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206(v=vs.85).aspx), the .NET [`System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable(v=vs.110).aspx) method, or the CRT function [`_putenv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83zh4e6k.aspx) (or similar CRT functions).

Comment: Also, thanks to the ANSI/Unicode distinction in Windows, it's very possible that "ANSI" and Unicode environment variables are stored in different locations anyway, meaning even if you figured out how to do this, `_putenv` might not affect anything that `_wgetenv` would retrieve in the same process, never mind in a different one. The same goes for the corresponding Windows API functions.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: Like all other ANSI implementations of the Windows API, [SetEnvironmentVariableA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206.aspx) converts it's arguments to UTF-16LE, calls `SetEnvironmentVariableW`, and returns. To my knowledge, the OS doesn't maintain two sets of environment variables for ANSI and Unicode.

Comment: Guys, read carefully (and letter by letter). I just need **read** environment of remote process (Raymond Chen, it's possible) and do not need suggestion on .NET...

Comment: Well, then, go ahead, and do so: [CreateRemoteThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437.aspx) followed by [GetEnvironmentStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683187.aspx).

Comment: No, no and no! After getting env pointer in my code:     if (!VirtualQueryEx(proc, env, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)) &&
      mbi.Protect == PAGE_NOACCESS || mbi.Protect == PAGE_EXECUTE
    ) {
      CloseHandle(proc);
      return -1;
    }
    buf = (TCHAR *)malloc(mbi.RegionSize);
    if (ReadProcessMemory(proc, mbi.AllocationBase, buf, mbi.RegionSize, NULL)) {
      //buf contains variables - how to get them?
    }
    free(buf);

Comment: Why do think you **must** use `ReadProcessMemory`? I don't see a convincing reason to go that route. I just outlined an alternative solution, that certainly is more robust as well, as it doesn't cause any race-conditions (like your proposed route would).

Comment: Why? Mmm, how you can explain then that fact what _tprintf(TEXT("%.*S\n"), mbi.RegionSize / sizeof(TCHAR), buf); prints first environment variable?

Comment: It's still not clear, why you insist on using an undocumented approach, when a documented and supported solution exists. Why the obsession with `ReadProcessMemory`?

Comment: ReadProcessMemory is an inherent race condition with the process calling SetEnvironmentVariable. It is also relying on mass quantities of undocumented/unsupported techniques.

Comment: @kate: We have sufficiently established, that calling `ReadProcessMemory` cannot reliably retrieve the environment of another process. Why keep barking up the wrong tree? Why do you insist, that you absolutely must use `ReadProcessMemory`, instead of using an alternative, that can work reliable? Please try to answer that question without using the following list of words: *"idiots"*, *"stupid"*, *"loosers"* (including its properly spelled pendant *"losers"*). Good luck (you'll need it).

Comment: Please avoid insulting other Stack Overflow members and stay professional.

Answer (score 0):

first of all your code only for x86, but how about x64 systems ? on x64 you must run from x64 code for access environment of x64 processes. but how about Wow64 processes ? they have 2 environments ! 1 naive and 1 Wow and this is not equal strings. so task can be enough complex. but however of course exist solution.

```
NTSTATUS ReadProcessEnv(HANDLE hProcess, PVOID Environment, PWSTR* ppsz)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

    if (0 > (status = ZwQueryVirtualMemory(hProcess, Environment, MemoryBasicInformation, &mbi, sizeof(mbi), 0))) return status;

    if (mbi.State != MEM_COMMIT || mbi.Type != MEM_PRIVATE)
    {
        return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    }

    mbi.RegionSize -= RtlPointerToOffset(mbi.BaseAddress, Environment);

    //Environment must be WCHAR aligned and how minimum 2*sizeof(WCHAR) size
    if (mbi.RegionSize < 2*sizeof(WCHAR) || ((ULONG_PTR)Environment & (__alignof(WCHAR) - 1)))
    {
        return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    }

    if (mbi.RegionSize > 0x10000)// >64Kb Environment ??
    {
        mbi.RegionSize = 0x10000;
    }

    if (PWSTR buf = new WCHAR[mbi.RegionSize])
    {
        if (0 <= (status = ZwReadVirtualMemory(hProcess, Environment, buf, mbi.RegionSize, 0)))
        {
            buf[mbi.RegionSize - 2] = 0;
            buf[mbi.RegionSize - 1] = 0;
            *ppsz = buf;

            return STATUS_SUCCESS;
        }
        delete buf;

        return status;
    }

    return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
}

NTSTATUS ReadProcessEnv(HANDLE hProcess, PWSTR* ppsz)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;
    _RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS* ProcessParameters;
    PVOID Environment;

    if (
        0 > (status = ZwQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, &pbi, sizeof(pbi), 0))
        ||
        0 > (status = ZwReadVirtualMemory(hProcess, &pbi.PebBaseAddress->ProcessParameters, &ProcessParameters, sizeof(PVOID), 0))
        ||
        0 > (status = ZwReadVirtualMemory(hProcess, &ProcessParameters->Environment, &Environment, sizeof(PVOID), 0))
        ) 
        return status;

    return ReadProcessEnv(hProcess, Environment, ppsz);
}

#ifdef _WIN64

NTSTATUS ReadProcessEnvWow(HANDLE hProcess, PWSTR* ppsz)
{
    ULONG WowPeb, ProcessParameters;
    NTSTATUS status;
    PVOID Environment = 0;

    if (0 > (status = ZwQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessWow64Information, &WowPeb, sizeof(PVOID), 0))) return status;

    if (!WowPeb)
    {
        return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }

    enum {
        ofs32_ProcessParameters = 0x10,
        ofs32_Environment = 0x48
    };

    if (
        0 > (status = ZwReadVirtualMemory(hProcess, RtlOffsetToPointer(WowPeb, ofs32_ProcessParameters), &ProcessParameters, sizeof(ULONG), 0))
        ||
        0 > (status = ZwReadVirtualMemory(hProcess, RtlOffsetToPointer(ProcessParameters, ofs32_Environment), &Environment, sizeof(ULONG), 0))
        ) 
        return status;

    return ReadProcessEnv(hProcess, Environment, ppsz);
}
#endif

NTSTATUS ReadProcessEnv(
                        PCLIENT_ID cid, 
                        PWSTR* ppsz, 
                        PNTSTATUS pstatus
#ifdef _WIN64
                        , 
                        PWSTR* ppszWow, 
                        PNTSTATUS pstatusWow
#endif
                        )
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    NTSTATUS status = ZwOpenProcess(&hProcess, PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ, &zoa, cid);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        *ppsz = 0;
        *pstatus = ReadProcessEnv(hProcess, ppsz);
#ifdef _WIN64
        *ppszWow = 0;
        *pstatusWow = ReadProcessEnvWow(hProcess, ppszWow);
#endif
        ZwClose(hProcess);
    }

    return status;
}

void DumpEnv(PCWSTR sz)
{
    while (*sz)
    {
        DbgPrint("%S\n", sz);
        sz += wcslen(sz) + 1;
    }
}

void test(PCLIENT_ID cid)
{
    PWSTR env, envWow;
    NTSTATUS status, s;

#ifdef _WIN64
    NTSTATUS sWow;
#endif

    if (0 <= (status = ReadProcessEnv(cid, &env, &s
#ifdef _WIN64
        , &envWow, &sWow
#endif
        )))
    {
        if (0 <= s)
        {
            DumpEnv(env);
            delete env;
        }

#ifdef _WIN64
        if (0 <= sWow)
        {
            if (envWow)
            {
                DumpEnv(envWow);
                delete envWow;
            }
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not need the code for x64, I need to somehow extract lines from buf in my code.

Comment: how extract lines - look - void DumpEnv(PCWSTR sz) - it dump line vy line. if need query some varitable by name - use RtlQueryEnvironmentVariable_U or RtlQueryEnvironmentVariable

Comment: DumpEnv just gets first variable, other are lost. I do not need query variables, I just need to get variables of a process.

Comment: "just gets first variable, other are lost." - you mistake. nothing lost."I just need to get variables" - i paste code, what you want more ?

Comment: @kate: Since you are struggling with understanding, how the environment block is laid out in memory, have a look at [GetEnvironmentStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683187.aspx).